# Check if current devise action and view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using the devise gem for authentication in my rails app. I would like to be able to hide my navbar partial if user is on a specific devise action and view. For example if user is currently in devise sessions new, I would like to hide my navbar partial. How would I accomplish this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `devise_controller?` helper. [Docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#devise_controller%3F-instance_method)

```
<%= if devise_controller? %>
  <!-- show partial -->
<% end %>
```

If you want to check for specific controller, use `request.controller`

```
<%= if request.controller == 'devise/registrations' %>
  <!-- show partial -->
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
<%= controller.name %>
<%= controller.action_name %>
```

Also there is:

```
<%= ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path(request.url)[:id] %>
```

All structures above let you know where you are now in the means of routing from the view/partial. Personally, I recommend you to use this, but take the logic out of the view in the helper where you can define mapping and conditional to get if you should render navbar.

Answer (score 1):

```
 in layouts

it will control user and guest folder

_nav.html.erb

  <% if !user_signed_in? %>
    <%= render '/layouts/nav_guest' %>
 <% else %>
    <%= render '/layouts/nav_user'%>
  <%end%>
```

_nav.user.html.erb

```
        show user navbar in this folder
```

_nav.guest.html.erb

```
           show guest navbar in this folder
```

Comment: Thanks Adarsh, but I can't use <% if !user_signed_in? %> in devise/sessions/new.html.erb because it's in that view I want to hide the navbar.